# How to evaluate this integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(ax)}{(ax)^2\sqrt{x^2+bi}} dx$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Evaluate-

> $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(ax)}{(ax)^2\sqrt{x^2+bi}} dx$$

where $a>0$ and $b>0$ are two given constants and $i$ is an imaginary unit.
I have no clue how to solve this problem. I tried to use the Residue theorem to imitate the method of calculating the Dirichlet integral, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is there any motivation? Mathematica evaluates to the dreaded Meijer-G function.